# CSS class toggle with jquery on different id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write some Jquery code for toggling two different class on different ids. 
Since the CMS strips out inline css, I need to find a solution for "display:none"
I have written two css classes, in hopes of toggling between them, but not really sure if this is the direction to go .
I'm very new to Stack and Jquery so any info or corrections are welcomed
Here is the code:

**CSS**

```
.displaynone{
    display:none;
}
.displayblock{
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML & JAVASCRIPT**

```
<form>
    <input onclick="javascript:resetForm();document.forms[0].reset();" type="reset" value="Reset" />&#160;
    <br />
    <br />
    <h4>Are you number 1?</h4>
    <label>
        <input name="one" onclick="unhide('hidden-input', this, 'hidden-input2')" type="radio" value="1" /> Yes

        <br />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="one" onclick="unhide('hidden-input2', this, 'hidden-input')" type="radio" value="2" /> No

        <br />
    </label>
    <div id="hidden-input2" style="display: none;">
        <p>If you are not , please download:

            <br />
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <span style="font-size: x-small;">number one</span>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="hidden-input" style="display: none;">
        <hr />
        <h4>Were you selected for too many hours?</h4>
        <label>
            <input name="hours" onclick="unhide('hidden-input3', this, 'hidden-input4')" type="radio" value="1" /> Yes

            <br />
        </label>
        <div id="hidden-input3" style="display: none;">
            <p>If you were selected for too many hours, please download:

                <br />
                <a href="#" target="blank">
                    <span style="font-size: x-small;">Hours</span>
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <label>
            <input name="hours" onclick="unhide('hidden-input4', this, 'hidden-input3')" type="radio" value="2" /> No

            <br />
        </label>
        <div id="hidden-input4" style="display: none;">
            <hr />
            <h4>Were you selected for number 3?</h4>
            <label>
                <input name="gpa" onclick="unhide('hidden-input5', this, 'hidden-input6')" type="radio" value="1" /> Yes

                <br />
            </label>
            <div id="hidden-input5" style="display: none;">
                <p>If you were selected for number 3, please download:

                    <br />
                    <a href="#" target="blank">
                        <span style="font-size: x-small;">Form for Three </span>
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <label>
                <input name="gpa" onclick="unhide('hidden-input6', this, 'hidden-input5')" type="radio" value="2" /> No

                <br />
            </label>
            <div id="hidden-input6" style="display: none;">
                <p>Were you selected for 4 :

                    <br />
                    <a href="#" target="blank">
                        <span style="font-size: x-small;">Form for 4</span>
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>undefined
</form>
```

Comment: It's generally better to avoid `onclick` and other inline event handlers. Instead, create a `script` tag and use a `document.ready` block with your event handlers. Where's `unhide()`?

Comment: Your CMS probably doesn't block inline styles after rendering, so you can simply use jQuery's `show()` and `hide()` methods after load.

Comment: Your question would be better if you simplified your markup to one example and explained what event should show or hide what element(s).

Answer (score 1):

change your element to default as display:block and define a class

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

and use this to toggle that class on/off

`$('#YOURID').toggleClass("hidden")`

Answer (score 0):

Easier to just have the hidden class and remove it when you want to show the element. That way you don't have to worry about altering inline, block and table display properties.

```
// hide the thing
$('.thing').addClass('displaynone');

// show the thing
$('.thing').removeClass('displaynone');
```

Answer (score 0):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/401/ something like this? i started recreating the logic, but i didnt finish it. you should get a gist of what's going, and if you have any questions on it, let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = $(this).val();
        console.log(name, value);
        if (name == 'one') { // if number 1 question
            if (value == 2) { 
                $('#hidden-input2').show(); // if no, show the download text
            }
            else {
                $('#hidden-input2').hide(); // if yes, hide the dl text
            }
            $('#hidden-input').show(); // always show the hours question
        }
        if (name == 'hours') {  // if hours question
            if (value == 2) {
                $('#hidden-input4').show() // if no, show number 3 question
            }
            else {
                $('#hidden-input4').hide() // if no, hide number 3 question
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes this is generally what I am trying to accomplish! Thanks if I have any questions, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally advisable to avoid targeting IDs, and instead use common classes inside grouping wrappers.

```
 <div>
    <label>
        <input name="one" class="selector yes" type="radio" value="1" />Yes
        <br />
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="one" class="selector no" type="radio" value="2" />No
        <br />
    </label>
    <div class="followup yes hidden">
        <p>If you are not , please download:
            <br /> <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <span style="font-size: x-small;">number one</span>
        </a>

        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="followup no hidden">
        <hr />
         <h4>Were you selected for too many hours?</h4>

    </div>
</div>

$('.selector').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('label').siblings('.followup').hide();

    if ($(this).is('.yes')) {
        $(this).closest('label').siblings('.followup.yes').show();
    } else {
        $(this).closest('label').siblings('.followup.no').show();
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dnv1nspd/)**

This single function is reusable for any number of groupings having the same structure, even if nested.

**[Nested demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dnv1nspd/4/)**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and all of your feedback its really helpful.